# Import States and Functions to a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, react-hooks, state

Is it possible to import states and functions on a functional React Component to make it cleaner?

Here's how my code looks like as of the moment:

```
import React from 'react'
//more imports...

const Dashboard = () => {

  const [] = useState()
  //more states here..

  const fetch = asycn () => {
    //more code..
  }

 //more functions here...

  return (
    <>
    </>
  )
}
```

However, I would like to know if it is possible to separate all states and functions so that my react component file would just look like this:

```
import React from 'react'
//more imports...
//import states and functions

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <>
    </>
  )
}
```

are there any other way to import it for me to use the data inside this component? (other than custom hooks to minimize my code)

Comment: If the function is used in more than one component you can try turning it into a hook, if that makes sense. If it's a utility function, it should exist outside anyway. Importing and using functions is trivial. state is a different matter though, you cannot import state definitions. If you want to separate logic and JSX you can do that by wrapping a "dumb" component (which does all the rendering) in a "smart" component (which contains states and logic). Also, if you tend to have huge JSX blocks and lots of "handleX" functions, consider splitting up your component.

Comment: Hi Thanks for this one. I think it would be great to separate dumb and smart components and break them down into pieces as mentioned. You could post this as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Redux,
It is used for centeralizing state in a global store which can be accessed throughout the applicaiton.

However you will need to use a hook, useSelector() to acess the state,
and useDispatch() to dispatch a new state.

You can also pass down state through props from at parent component,

```
const Dashboard = ({state, setState}) => {
  return (
    <>
    </>
  )
}
```

However, then the parent component will have many `const [state, setState] = useState()`

Answer (score 0):

for complex state's and what you are describe
you need to use redux.
https://redux.js.org/introduction/examples

for local and simple state useState is the optimally option

I hope my answer guided you